# Writing into plists in iOS 5.0.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I am using the following code to write into a plist:

```
  NSMutableArray *d = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FavoritesTaxi" ofType:@"plist"]];
[d addObject:self.dataItem];


// write dictionary to plist
[d writeToFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FavoritesTaxi" ofType:@"plist"] atomically:YES];
[d release];
```

I tested this code on 4 different devices( 2 simulators and 2 real iphones).
It worked on the following :
iPhone 4.3 simulator
iPhone 5.0 simulator
iPhone 4.3 Real Device

But it didn't work on the following :
iPhone 5.0.1 Real Device.

I really do not know why this is happening to this device. Any ideas why? And what is the solution to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the main bundle on the device, you don't have the privileges to do that. So you can't write a plist into the main bundle. I doubt this worked on the 4.3 device, it just may not have given you an error.

You should save data into the documents directory, there are tons of code samples on here for getting a path to the documents directory.

Comment: You're right. So now, if I created a plist in my project and I want to put it in the documents directory, I have to select the plist, open utilities, and in the "location", I should select "relative to developer directory"? and then instead of writing the file in the mainbundle, I write it for documents directory? or is there more modification in the code?

Comment: Typically if you have an existing plist which the user can then modify and re-save, you'd include it in the bundle in the first instance, then copy it out to the documents directory in code on your first run. Again there are lots of samples out there, or you can ask a new question.